# Are there any limits on the number of blocks that can be used in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits, limits

Are there any limits on the number of blocks that can be used in a flow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no maximum number of elements you can use in a Flow, but there is an overall execution limit of 2,000 elements in a flow. The more elements you use, the more you risk running in to this limit. For example, if you need to process 200 records, each record can only afford to use 10 elements.